# Creating ArcGIS tile service from equirectangular image of Mars

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, tiles, tile-map-service

I have a high-resolution image of mars (equirectangular projection) that I've rendered and want to create a tile service from (similar to [Mars Colorized Mosaic](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1efb16809db84f0c892b9b0662dab0c8)), using ArcGIS Pro.

How do I build a similar tile service, with only one, high-resolution image to start with? Ideally, I would want a tile service that provides pictures in different resolutions based on the zoom level, similar to the example given above.

The picture I'm working with looks something like this (with 46080x23040 resolution)
[image: equirectangular image]

Any good documentation, tutorials or pointers on where to start?

Edit: I've seen something similar been performed in MapBox, it could also be an alternative to host a tile-service there, and use a TileLayer in ArcGIS to fetch the tiles.